# IPv6 only subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, ipv6, godaddy

I have a domain and shared hosting at godaddy. I've created a subdomain and added an ipv6 proxy from sixy.ch in my aaaa records. Nov I have IPv4 a v6 connectivity too, but i want to block access from IPv4 adresses to get an Ipv6 only subdomain. How can I force an IPv6 connection? Already asked at godaddy support but they just paste general answers from the FAQ.

Edit: Can I block all IPv4 connections in .htaccess file and force the client to connect with IPv6 if he has both protocols installed?

Comment: GoDaddy is also just a poor quality provider, and often doesn't support advanced features.

Comment: Get native ipv6, and get rid of proxies/tunnels.  Once you've done that, you need to set AAAA records, and delete the A records.

Answer (score 2):

You want the IPv6 subdomain to only have the AAAA record, no A record. This should be configurable in the DNS zone editor at Godaddy, even though I have never used Godaddy myself.

Comment: Tried that, but this proxy just tunnels the ipv6 traffic to ipv4, when I deleted the A record, the domain went down.

Comment: @LahonZeravosch: Just a sanity check, but are you sure that the AAAA record existed after you deleted the A record? The GoDaddy domain tool might be doing something wrong with the AAAA record.

Comment: Yes, the AAAA record is there, but as I said, this is not native ipv6, just a tunnel. The subdomain loads if i'm using http://[IPv6example]/ but just if the A record is added too.

Comment: If it's not native ipv6, but just a tunnel, you can't expect clients to user pure native ipv6.  It doesn't make sense.

Comment: What to do if there is also * subdomain?

Comment: OK. Seems working with * too. Was a dns propagation.